# No comprobar + subjuntivo

Tags: gramática

Quisiera confirmar si el verbo que va después de "no comprobar" tiene que ser en forma subjuntiva en el párrafo "[no se comprobó que ninguna de estas afecciones lleve al cáncer de próstata, pero alguien podría tener una o ambas afecciones y también cáncer de próstata.](https://www.cancer.gov/espanol/tipos/prostata/hoja-informativa-psa)" ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la oración:

- No se comprobó que ninguna de estas afecciones **lleve** al cáncer de próstata, pero alguien podría tener una o ambas afecciones y también cáncer de próstata.

es necesario el subjuntivo por dos motivos:

1. El doble negativo ("no" / "ninguna").
2. La proposición coordinada introducida por "pero".

Ref. (1), si se usara "no" solamente, se podría usar indicativo si hubiera más certeza acerca de que alguna de esas afecciones o todas ellas llevan al cáncer de próstata, aunque no esté comprobado:

- No se comprobó que estas afecciones **llevan** al cáncer de próstata. (Creemos que sí, pero no está comprobado).

Con el doble negativo, la certeza se diluye y se requiere subjuntivo.

Ref. (2), la proposición introducida por "pero" debe contraponerse a la anterior: no hay certeza sobre la primera (subjuntivo "lleven") pero hay certeza respecto de la posibilidad de la coexistencia de ambas enfermedades ("podrían").

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones!